# Find minimum values

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I thought about it alot .

I am not getting any idea . can anybody provide me a hint

Comment: I am not getting appropriate tag for this . Can anyone edit it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha^2+2 \beta^2+3\alpha=1+\gamma^2 \\
2 \alpha^2+ 4 \beta^2=1+\gamma^2 +5 \beta
\end{eqnarray*}
Mutliply the first equation by $2$ and subtract the second equation. We have $ 6\alpha +5 \beta=2$.

Now
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha^2+ \beta^2= \alpha^2+ \frac{(2-6\alpha)^2}{25} = \frac{61\alpha^2-24 \alpha+4}{25} = \frac{(61\alpha-12)^2 +100}{25 \times 61} 
\end{eqnarray*}
So (A) is correct.
Similarly
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha^2+ \beta^2-2 \alpha+1= \alpha^2-2 \alpha+1+ \frac{(2-6\alpha)^2}{25} = \frac{61\alpha^2-74 \alpha+29}{25} = \frac{(61\alpha-37)^2 +400}{25 \times 61} 
\end{eqnarray*}
So (C) is correct.